# Does order of Select statements matter when you have a stored procedure with multiple select statements being read by Dapper?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that loads the schedule data for departments in my business. I have multiple select statements that are read using dapper to load them into a c# method.  I managed to optimise the procedure to get down to loading in about 6 seconds each time from well over a minute. However, recently it has started to slow down, and one of the departments called me this morning to say that it was timing out.

I load the procedure into SSMS and run it from there, and it loads in 6 seconds. They then load the C# method into visual studio and its taking over a minute to load. So I step through each of the dapper reading statements, and it gets stuck on one statement, for over a minute. Then after that everything takes less than a second to load.

Then I moved the statement that was slowing things down up towards the top of the list, and it loads the whole thing in 3 seconds now. Why would the order of the select statement affect the speed with which Dapper is able to load the procedure?

I have put a couple of comments in so you can see what was moved:
//slow statement moved to here   -- this is the place earlier in the chain where the slow statement (`orderDesignProcessSteps`) was moved)
//here is where slow statement used to be -- this is the placed further down the chain where that statement used to load

C# code:

```
public static List<Job> GetOverviewJobsV2(List<int> JobTypes, int SupplierId, bool FindDesignStock)
{
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Settings.ConnectionString))
        {
            DataTable dt = Common.DataTableHelpers.CreateIntDataTable(JobTypes);

            using (var multi = conn.QueryMultiple("PR_GetOverviewJobs_V5", new { JobTypes = dt.AsTableValuedParameter("dbo.IntTable"), SupplierId }, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure))
            {
                var jobs = multi.Read<Job>().ToList();

                bool orderVersion0required = jobs.Exists(x => x.OrderVersion == 0);

                try
                {
                    //orderversion 0
                    var designData = new List<DesignProcessData>();
                    var children = new List<DesignProcessData>();
                    var designStatuses = new List<DesignProcessStep>();
                    
                    var orderItemsV1 = new List<OrderItem>();
                    var jobItemsV1 = new List<JobItem>();
                    var despatchItems = new List<DespatchItem>();

                    if (orderVersion0required)
                    { 
                        designData = multi.Read<DesignProcessData>().OrderBy(x => x.ApplicationDate).ToList();
                        children = multi.Read<DesignProcessData>().ToList();
                        designStatuses = multi.Read<DesignProcessStep>().ToList();
                    
                        orderItemsV1 = multi.Read<OrderItem>().ToList();
                        jobItemsV1 = multi.Read<JobItem>().ToList();
                        despatchItems = multi.Read<DespatchItem>().ToList();
                    }

                    //orderversion 1
                    var masterDesigns = multi.Read<DesignProcessData>().ToList();
                    var orderDesigns = multi.Read<OrderDesign>().ToList();

                    //slow statement moved to here
                    var orderDesignProcessSteps = multi.Read<DesignProcessStep>().ToList();
                    var masterDesignProcessSteps = multi.Read<DesignProcessStep>().ToList();

                    //orderversion 1
                    var orderItemsV2 = multi.Read<OrderItem>().ToList();
                    var jobItemsV2 = multi.Read<OrderItem>().ToList();
                    var jobItemIdsLinkedToOrderItemIds = multi.Read<JobItem>().ToList();
                    var despatchItemsV2 = multi.Read<DespatchItem>().ToList();

                    var finishing = multi.Read<FinishingProcessData>().ToList();

                    var filestoreFiles = multi.Read<FileStoreFile>().ToList();
                    var masterDesignFileStore = multi.Read<FileStoreFile>().ToList();

                    var staffMembers = multi.Read<StaffMember>().ToList();
                    var logs = multi.Read<LogEntry>().ToList();

                    var potentialJobs = multi.Read<Job>().ToList();

                    //orderversion0
                    var designColours = new List<PrintColour>();
                    var stencils = new List<Stencil>();
                    stencils = null;

                    var screens = new List<Screen>();
                    screens = null;

                    if (orderVersion0required)
                    {
                        designColours = multi.Read<PrintColour>().ToList();

                        if (JobTypes.Exists(jt => jt == 1 || jt == 6))
                        {
                            stencils = multi.Read<Stencil>().ToList();
                            screens = multi.Read<Screen>().ToList();
                        }
                    }

                    //orderversion 1
                    var designColoursv2 = multi.Read<PrintColour>().ToList();
                    var colourways = multi.Read<PrintColourway>().ToList();
                    var colourWayColours = multi.Read<MyStore.Design.PrintColour>().OrderBy(x => x.ColourNumber).ToList();
                    var designStock = multi.Read<DesignStock>().ToList();

                    var stencilsv2 = new List<Stencil>();
                    stencilsv2 = null;

                    var screensv2 = new List<Screen>();
                    screensv2 = null;

                    if (JobTypes.Exists(jt => jt == 1 || jt == 6))
                    {
                        stencilsv2 = multi.Read<Stencil>().ToList();
                        screensv2 = multi.Read<Screen>().ToList();
                    }

                    //here is where slow statement used to be

                    var itemPurchaseOrders = multi.Read<ItemPurchaseOrder>().ToList();
                    var purchaseOrderItems = multi.Read<PurchasingItem>().ToList();
                    var purchaseOrderBookingDatas = multi.Read<BookingData>().ToList();
                    var purchaseOrderBookingItems = multi.Read<BookingItem>().ToList();
                    var itemFaults = multi.Read<ItemFault>().ToList();
                    var orderItemIdsLinkedToPurchaseItems = multi.Read<PurchasingItem>().ToList();
                    var stockLocations = multi.Read<StockLocation>().ToList();

                    var highlightColours = multi.Read<Core.Site.HighlightColour>().ToList();
                    var serviceSuppliers = multi.Read<ServiceSupplier>().ToList();
```

T-SQL Procedure:

If you want to see the bit that was slowing it down that was moved, it's got a comment directly above it called --design process stepsv2 orderDesignProcessSteps.  It ends with WHERE olddps.MasterDesignId = 0

```
USE [LaunchPad3_Production]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[PR_GetOverviewJobs_V5]    Script Date: 14/12/2022 13:15:05 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PR_GetOverviewJobs_V5] 
    @JobTypes IntTable READONLY,
    @SupplierId INT = 1
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
------------------------------------------------------------------------TEMP TABLES
    --temptable for jobs
    SELECT
        prj.Id AS JobId,
        ob.Id AS OrderId,
        prj.DesignId,
        ob.GlobalId,
        ob.OrderVersion
    INTO #Jobs
    FROM
        LaunchPad3_Production.dbo.PR_Job prj
            INNER JOIN Launchpad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.ORDER_Base ob ON ob.Id = prj.OrderId
            INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.ORDERPROCESS_Base opb ON opb.OrderId = prj.OrderId
            INNER JOIN @JobTypes jt ON jt.Int = prj.JobType
    WHERE
        prj.completed = 0
        AND ob.deleted = 0
        AND opb.IsProcessed = 1 
        AND opb.Complete = 0
        AND opb.HoldInStoke = 0
        AND prj.SupplierId = @SupplierId

        --AND prj.Id = 46167


    DECLARE @NumberOf0VersionOrders int = (SELECT COUNT(OrderVersion) FROM #Jobs WHERE OrderVersion = 0)

------------------------------------------------------------------------SELECT QUERIES
    
    -- Get all jobs
    SELECT DISTINCT
        opb.*,
        prj.*,
        CONVERT(DATE,opb.DespatchDate) AS DespatchDate,
        CONVERT(DATE,prj.ProductionDate) AS ApplicationDate,
        prj.Id as JobId,
        ISNULL(prj.Notes, '') AS JobNotes,
        ub.CompanyName,
        ub.FirstName,
        ub.LastName,
        ob.OrderVersion,
        opb.DespatchDateType AS DespatchType
    FROM LaunchPad3_Production.dbo.PR_Job prj
        INNER JOIN #Jobs ej ON ej.jobid = prj.id
        INNER JOIN Launchpad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.ORDER_Base ob ON ob.Id = prj.OrderId
        INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.ORDERPROCESS_Base opb ON opb.OrderId = prj.OrderId
        INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_Core.dbo.USER_Base ub ON ob.UserId = ub.Id

IF (@NumberOf0VersionOrders != 0)
    BEGIN
        -- order version 0 parent designs
        SELECT distinct opd.*, od.*, db.*, 
            dpm.ViewPoint as TemplateViewPoint, 
            dp.Type as DesignPosition,
            db.ApplicationTypeId,
            opd.ProcessTypeId as ProcessId,
            od.CategoryId,
            od.DesignId,
            dp.Type AS DesignPosition,
            od.Id,
            db.Name,
            od.OrderId,
            DesignPositionId AS PositionId,
            opd.OrderDesignId,
            opd.OrderDesignId as DesignId,
            opd.ApplicationDate,
            od.OrderId,
            dpr.Department,
            dlpc.ParentId, dlpc.ChildId, 
            dpr.WeedingRequired,
            dpr.Name AS ProcessType
        FROM #Jobs pj 
            INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.ORDER_Design od ON od.orderid = pj.orderid
            INNER JOIN Launchpad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.DESIGN_Base db ON od.DesignId = db.Id
            INNER JOIN Launchpad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.DESIGN_TYPE_Position dp ON dp.Id = od.DesignPositionId
            INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.ORDERPROCESS_Design opd ON opd.OrderDesignId = od.DesignId
            INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.DESIGN_Process dpr ON dpr.id = opd.ProcessTypeId
            left JOIN Launchpad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.DESIGN_PositionMap dpm ON dpm.TemplateId = od.CategoryId and dpm.PositionId = od.DesignPositionId AND dpm.GlobalId = pj.GlobalId
            LEFT JOIN LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.DESIGN_LINK_Parent_Child dlpc ON dlpc.childid = od.DesignId 
        WHERE dlpc.ParentId IS NULL OR dlpc.parentid = od.designid

        -- order version 1 child designs
        SELECT distinct opd.*, od.*, db.*,  
            dpm.ViewPoint as TemplateViewPoint, 
            dp.Type as DesignPosition,
            db.ApplicationTypeId,
            opd.ProcessTypeId as ProcessId,
            od.CategoryId,
            od.DesignId,
            dp.Type AS DesignPosition,
            od.Id,
            db.Name,
            od.OrderId,
            DesignPositionId AS PositionId,
            opd.OrderDesignId,
            opd.OrderDesignId as DesignId,
            opd.ApplicationDate,
            od.OrderId,
            dpr.Department,
            dlpc.ParentId, dlpc.ChildId
            --, pj.designid, od.designid
        FROM #Jobs pj 
            INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.ORDER_Design od ON od.orderid = pj.orderid
            INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.DESIGN_LINK_Parent_Child dlpc ON dlpc.childid = od.DesignId 
            INNER JOIN Launchpad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.DESIGN_Base db ON od.DesignId = db.Id
            INNER JOIN Launchpad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.DESIGN_TYPE_Position dp ON dp.Id = od.DesignPositionId
            INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.ORDERPROCESS_Design opd ON opd.OrderDesignId = od.DesignId
            INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.DESIGN_Process dpr ON dpr.id = opd.ProcessTypeId
            INNER JOIN Launchpad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.DESIGN_PositionMap dpm ON dpm.TemplateId = od.CategoryId and dpm.PositionId = od.DesignPositionId AND dpm.GlobalId = pj.GlobalId

        --design statuses v1
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            olddps.*,
            dps.*,
            dpss.*,
            dpdps.*,
            olddps.DesignId,
            olddps.PathStepId as Id,
            dps.StatusText as DisplayText,
            dpss.StatusText AS StatusText,
            dpdps.StepOrder as PathOrder,
            dp.ApplicationTypeId AS ProcessTypeId
        FROM LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.ORDERPROCESS_LINK_Design_DesignPathStep olddps
            INNER JOIN Launchpad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.ORDER_Design od1 ON od1.DesignId = olddps.DesignId
            INNER JOIN #Jobs j ON j.OrderId = od1.OrderId
            INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.ORDERPROCESS_DesignPathStep dps ON olddps.PathStepId = dps.Id
            INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.ORDERPROCESS_DesignPathStepStatus dpss ON olddps.PathStepStatusId = dpss.Id
            INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.ORDERPROCESS_Design od ON od.OrderDesignId = olddps.DesignId
            INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.ORDERPROCESS_DesignPath dp ON dp.ApplicationTypeId = od.ProcessTypeId AND dp.GlobalId = j.GlobalId
            INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.ORDERPROCESS_LINK_DesignPath_DesignPathStep dpdps ON dpdps.PathStepId = olddps.PathStepId AND dpdps.PathId = dp.Id


        --order items v1
        SELECT distinct oi.*, dt.Name AS TemplateName, Qty as ItemQty, ej.JobId
        FROM Launchpad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.ORDER_Item oi
            INNER JOIN Launchpad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.design_template dt on dt.Id = oi.TemplateId
            INNER JOIN #Jobs ej ON ej.OrderId = oi.OrderId

        --jobItems v1
        SELECT ji.* 
        FROM LaunchPad3_Production.dbo.PR_JobItem ji
            INNER JOIN #Jobs ej ON ej.jobid = ji.jobid

        --despatch datav1
        SELECT DISTINCT  db.*,di.*
        FROM
            LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.despatch_item di
            INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.DESPATCH_Base db ON db.id = di.DespatchId
            inner JOIN Launchpad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.order_item oi ON oi.id = di.OrderItemId
            INNER JOIN #Jobs ej ON ej.orderid = oi.OrderId
        WHERE db.Deleted= 0
    END

    --master designs order version 2
    SELECT DISTINCT
        dm.*,
        0 AS DesignId,
        dtd.Type AS DesignType,
        dm.Id AS MasterDesignId,
        pc.HexCode as FontColourCode,
        pc.Name AS FontColourName,
        df.Name as FontName,
        dta.Type AS DesignApplicationType,
        dm.ProcessTypeId as ProcessId,
        dp.Name AS ProcessType,
        dp.Department,
        dp.WeedingRequired,
        pjlmd.JobId
    FROM Launchpad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.Order_Design_V2 od
        INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_Production.dbo.PR_Job_LINK_MasterDesign pjlmd ON pjlmd.MasterDesignId = od.MasterDesignId
        INNER JOIN #Jobs j ON j.JobId = pjlmd.JobId
        INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.DESIGN_Master dm ON dm.Id = od.MasterDesignId
        INNER JOIN Launchpad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.DESIGN_TYPE_Application dta ON dta.Id = dm.ApplicationTypeId
        inner JOIN Launchpad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.DESIGN_TYPE_Design dtd ON dtd.Id = dm.DesignTypeId
        LEFT JOIN Launchpad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.DESIGN_PrintColours pc ON Dm.FontColourId = pc.Id
        LEFT JOIN Launchpad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.DESIGN_Font df ON df.Id = Dm.FontId
        LEFT JOIN LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.DESIGN_Process dp ON dp.Id = dm.ProcessTypeId
        
    -- order designs order version 2
    SELECT DISTINCT
        od.*,
        od.Id AS OrderDesignId,
        od.DesignPositionId AS PositionId,
        dpm.ViewPoint as TemplateView,
        dpm.ViewPoint,
        dtp.Type AS DesignPosition,
        pjlmd.JobId
    FROM Launchpad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.Order_Design_V2 od
        INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_Production.dbo.PR_Job_LINK_MasterDesign pjlmd ON pjlmd.MasterDesignId = od.MasterDesignId
        INNER JOIN #Jobs j ON j.JobId = pjlmd.JobId AND j.OrderId = od.OrderId
        INNER JOIN Launchpad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.DESIGN_TYPE_Position dtp ON dtp.Id = od.DesignPositionId
        INNER JOIN Launchpad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.ORDER_ITEM_V2 oi ON oi.Id = od.OrderItemId
        INNER JOIN Launchpad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.ORDER_Base ob ON ob.Id = od.OrderId
        INNER JOIN Launchpad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.PRODUCT_Base pb ON pb.Id = oi.ProductId
        INNER JOIN Launchpad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.DESIGN_PositionMap dpm on dpm.TemplateId = pb.TemplateId AND dpm.PositionId = od.DesignPositionId

    --design process stepsv2 orderDesignProcessSteps
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        olddps.*,
        dps.*,
        dpss.*,
        dpdps.*,
        olddps.PathStepId as Id,
        dps.StatusText as DisplayText,
        dpss.StatusText AS StatusText,
        dpdps.StepOrder as PathOrder,
        dp.ApplicationTypeId AS ProcessId
    FROM LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.ORDERPROCESS_LINK_Design_DesignPathStepV2 olddps
        INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.ORDERPROCESS_DesignPathStep dps ON olddps.PathStepId = dps.Id
        INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.ORDERPROCESS_DesignPathStepStatus dpss ON olddps.PathStepStatusId = dpss.Id
        INNER JOIN Launchpad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.Order_Design_V2 od ON  od.Id = olddps.DesignId
        INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_Production.dbo.PR_Job_LINK_MasterDesign pjlmd ON pjlmd.MasterDesignId = od.MasterDesignId
        INNER JOIN #Jobs j ON j.JobId = pjlmd.JobId
        INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.DESIGN_Master dm ON dm.Id = od.MasterDesignId
        INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.ORDERPROCESS_DesignPath dp ON dp.ApplicationTypeId = dm.ProcessTypeId AND dp.GlobalId = j.GlobalId
        INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.ORDERPROCESS_LINK_DesignPath_DesignPathStep dpdps ON dpdps.PathStepId = olddps.PathStepId AND dpdps.PathId = dp.Id
    WHERE olddps.MasterDesignId = 0

    --master design process stepsv2
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        olddps.*,
        dps.*,
        dpss.*,
        dpdps.*,
        olddps.PathStepId as Id,
        dps.StatusText as DisplayText,
        dpss.StatusText AS StatusText,
        dpdps.StepOrder as PathOrder,
        dp.ApplicationTypeId AS ProcessId
    FROM LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.ORDERPROCESS_LINK_Design_DesignPathStepV2 olddps
        INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.ORDERPROCESS_DesignPathStep dps ON olddps.PathStepId = dps.Id
        INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.ORDERPROCESS_DesignPathStepStatus dpss ON olddps.PathStepStatusId = dpss.Id
        INNER JOIN Launchpad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.Order_Design_V2 od ON  od.MasterDesignId = olddps.MasterDesignId
        INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_Production.dbo.PR_Job_LINK_MasterDesign pjlmd ON pjlmd.MasterDesignId = od.MasterDesignId
        INNER JOIN #Jobs j ON j.JobId = pjlmd.JobId
        INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.DESIGN_Master dm ON dm.Id = od.MasterDesignId
        INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.ORDERPROCESS_DesignPath dp ON dp.ApplicationTypeId = dm.ProcessTypeId AND dp.GlobalId = j.GlobalId
        INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.ORDERPROCESS_LINK_DesignPath_DesignPathStep dpdps ON dpdps.PathStepId = olddps.PathStepId AND dpdps.PathId = dp.Id
    WHERE olddps.MasterDesignId != 0

    --order itemsv2
    SELECT DISTINCT oi.*, S.Size AS SizeName, oi.Qty AS ItemQty
    FROM    Launchpad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.ORDER_ITEM_V2 oi
        INNER JOIN Launchpad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.PRODUCT_Size s ON oi.SizeId = s.Id
        INNER JOIN #Jobs j ON j.OrderId = oi.OrderId

    -- Job itemsv2
    SELECT DISTINCT 
    oiv.OrderId
    ,oiv.ProductId
    ,oiv.ProductCode
    ,oiv.ProductName
    ,oiv.ColourId
    ,oiv.SizeId
    ,oiv.ColourName
    ,oiv.TemplateId
    ,S.Size AS SizeName 
    ,pji.*
    ,dt.Name AS TemplateName
    FROM LaunchPad3_Production.dbo.PR_JobItem pji
        INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_Production.dbo.PR_JobItem_LINK_OrderItem pjiloi ON pjiloi.JobItemId = pji.Id
        INNER JOIN Launchpad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.ORDER_ITEM_V2 oiv ON oiv.Id = pjiloi.OrderItemId
        INNER JOIN Launchpad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.PRODUCT_Size s ON oiv.SizeId = s.Id
        INNER JOIN Launchpad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.ORDER_Base ob ON ob.Id = oiv.OrderId
        INNER JOIN Launchpad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.DESIGN_Template dt ON dt.Id = oiv.TemplateId
        INNER JOIN #Jobs j ON j.JobId = pji.JobId

    --job items linked to orderItemsv2
    SELECT DISTINCT pjiloi.*
    FROM LaunchPad3_Production.dbo.PR_JobItem pji
        INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_Production.dbo.PR_JobItem_LINK_OrderItem pjiloi ON pjiloi.JobItemId = pji.Id
        INNER JOIN Launchpad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.ORDER_ITEM_V2 oiv ON oiv.Id = pjiloi.OrderItemId
        INNER JOIN #Jobs j ON j.JobId = pji.JobId

    --despatch datav2
    SELECT DISTINCT di.*, db.* FROM
        LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.despatch_item di
        INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.DESPATCH_Base db ON db.id = di.DespatchId
        inner JOIN Launchpad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.ORDER_ITEM_V2 oiv ON oiv.id = di.OrderItemId
        INNER JOIN #Jobs ej ON ej.orderid = oiv.OrderId
    WHERE db.Deleted= 0

    -- get finishing
    SELECT DISTINCT
        f.Id,
        f.OrderId,
        f.Type,
        ISNULL(ft.Name, '') as TypeName,
        f.Method,
        ISNULL(fp.Name,'') AS MethodName,
        f.SupplierId,
        f.Notes,
        f.Date,
        ft.PackingDepartmentRequiredForFinishing,
        ISNULL(f.MediaLocation,'') AS MediaLocation,
        ISNULL(fp.PackingDepartmentRequiredForPacking,0) AS PackingDepartmentRequiredForPacking
    FROM LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.ORDERPROCESS_Finishing f
        Left JOIN LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.ORDERPROCESS_TYPE_Finishing ft ON ft.Id = f.Type
        Left JOIN LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.ORDERPROCESS_TYPE_Packing fp ON fp.Id = f.Method
        INNER JOIN #Jobs j ON j.OrderId = f.orderid

    -- order filestore
    SELECT DISTINCT ej.DesignId, ff.*, flfo.OrderId, flfo.FileTypeId as Type, flfo.DesignId AS OrderDesignId
    FROM LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.FILESTORE_File ff
        INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.FILESTORE_LINK_File_Order flfo ON ff.Id = flfo.FileId
        INNER JOIN #Jobs ej ON ej.orderid = flfo.OrderId

    --filestore files for design
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        ff.Id
       ,ff.Name
       ,ff.FilePath
       ,ff.Size
       ,ff.GlobalId
        ,flfo.FileId
       ,flfo.FileTypeId
       ,flfo.DesignId
       ,flfo.MasterDesignId
       ,flfo.ColourwayId
        ,flfo.FileTypeId as Type
        ,flfo.OrderId
    FROM LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.FILESTORE_File ff
        INNER JOIN  LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.FILESTORE_LINK_File_Order flfo ON ff.Id = flfo.FileId
        INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_Production.dbo.PR_Job_LINK_MasterDesign pjlmd ON pjlmd.MasterDesignId = flfo.MasterDesignId
        INNER JOIN #Jobs j ON j.JobId = pjlmd.JobId

    --staff members
    SELECT * FROM LaunchPad3_Core.dbo.USER_Base ub
        INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_Production.dbo.PR_StaffMember sm ON sm.UserId = ub.Id AND sm.GlobalId = ub.GlobalId
    WHERE ub.GlobalId = 29

    --log entries
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        pl.Id
       ,pl.JobId
       ,pl.OrderId
       ,pl.DesignId
       ,pl.UserId
       ,pl.StatusId AS Status
       ,pl.Notes
       ,pl.Date
    FROM LaunchPad3_Production.dbo.PR_Log pl 
        INNER JOIN  #Jobs ej ON ej.JobId = pl.JobId

    -- list of all other jobs
    EXEC LaunchPad3_Production.dbo.[PR_GetAllJobsForLiveOrders]

IF (@NumberOf0VersionOrders != 0)
    BEGIN
    -- get design colourways and print colours
        SELECT pc.id, cb.DesignId, pc.name, cb.Id as ColourWayId, pc.HexCode, clbc.PantoneMixed
        FROM #Jobs sp
            INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.ORDERPROCESS_LINK_Design_PrintColour oldpc ON oldpc.DesignId = sp.DesignId -- AND oldpc.PrintColourId = pc.Id
            INNER join LaunchPad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.DESIGN_PrintColours pc ON pc.Id = oldpc.PrintColourId -- clbc.ColourId
            INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.COLOURWAY_Base cb ON cb.DesignId = oldpc.DesignId -- sp.DesignId = cb.DesignId
            INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.COLOURWAY_LINK_Base_Colour clbc ON cb.Id = clbc.ColourwayId
        --WHERE sp.OrderVersion = 0

        IF EXISTS (SELECT int FROM @JobTypes WHERE Int = 1 OR int = 6)
            BEGIN
                --get the stencils
                SELECT DISTINCT sps.*
                , slss.ScreenId
                FROM 
                    #Jobs j
                    INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_Production.dbo.PR_SP_Stencil sps ON sps.OrderId = j.OrderId AND sps.DesignId = j.DesignId
                    INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_Production.dbo.PR_SP_LINK_Stencil_Screen slss ON slss.StencilId = sps.Id

                --get the screens
                SELECT DISTINCT spsc.* 
                FROM LaunchPad3_Production.dbo.PR_SP_Screen spsc
                    INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_Production.dbo.PR_SP_LINK_Stencil_Screen slss ON slss.ScreenId = spsc.Id
                    INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_Production.dbo.PR_SP_Stencil sps ON sps.Id = slss.StencilId
                    INNER JOIN #Jobs j ON j.DesignId = sps.DesignId
            END
END

    --design coloursv2
    SELECT  distinct
        dpc.*
        ,dpc.HexCode as ColourCode
        ,opc.ColourOnAllGarments 
        ,od.ColourWayId
        ,opc.ColourNumber
        ,od.MasterDesignId
        ,clbc.PantoneMixed
    FROM #Jobs j
        INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_Production.dbo.PR_Job_LINK_MasterDesign pjlmd ON pjlmd.JobId = j.JobId
        INNER JOIN Launchpad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.ORDER_Design_V2 od ON od.MasterDesignId = pjlmd.MasterDesignId
        INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.COLOURWAY_LINK_Base_Colour clbc ON od.ColourWayId = clbc.ColourwayId -- AND clbc.ColourwayId = od.ColourWayId
        INNER join LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.ORDERPROCESS_LINK_Design_PrintColour opc ON od.MasterDesignId = opc.MasterDesignId AND opc.PrintColourId = clbc.ColourId
        INNER join LaunchPad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.DESIGN_PrintColours dpc ON dpc.Id = opc.PrintColourId    


    --master design colourwaysv2
    SELECT DISTINCT cb.* 
    FROM
        #Jobs j
        INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_Production.dbo.PR_Job_LINK_MasterDesign pjlmd ON pjlmd.JobId = j.JobId
        INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.COLOURWAY_Base cb ON pjlmd.MasterDesignId = cb.MasterDesignId
        
    --print colours from master design colourwaysv2
        SELECT DISTINCT
        dpc.*
        ,cb.*
        ,cb.Id AS ColourWayId
        ,dpc.Id
        ,clbc.ColourNumber
        ,clbc.PantoneMixed
        FROM
            #Jobs j 
            INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_Production.dbo.PR_Job_LINK_MasterDesign pjlmd ON pjlmd.JobId = j.JobId
            inner JOIN LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.COLOURWAY_Base cb ON cb.MasterDesignId = pjlmd.MasterDesignId
            INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.COLOURWAY_LINK_Base_Colour clbc ON cb.Id = clbc.ColourwayId
            INNER join LaunchPad3_MyStore_2015.dbo.DESIGN_PrintColours dpc ON dpc.Id = clbc.ColourId

    --designstock
    SELECT * 
    FROM LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.Design_Master_Stock_LINK_OrderId dmsloi
        INNER join #Jobs j ON j.OrderId = dmsloi.OrderId

IF EXISTS (SELECT int FROM @JobTypes WHERE Int = 1 OR int = 6)
    BEGIN
        --get the stencilsv2
        SELECT DISTINCT sps.*
        , slss.ScreenId
        FROM 
            #Jobs j
            INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_Production.dbo.PR_Job_LINK_MasterDesign pjlmd ON pjlmd.JobId = j.JobId
            INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_Production.dbo.PR_SP_Stencil sps ON pjlmd.MasterDesignId = sps.MasterDesignId
            LEFT JOIN LaunchPad3_Production.dbo.PR_SP_LINK_Stencil_Screen slss ON slss.StencilId = sps.Id

        --get the screensv2
        SELECT DISTINCT spsc.* ,slss.StencilId
        FROM 
            #Jobs j
            INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_Production.dbo.PR_Job_LINK_MasterDesign pjlmd ON pjlmd.JobId = j.JobId
            INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_Production.dbo.PR_SP_Stencil sps ON sps.MasterDesignId = pjlmd.MasterDesignId
            INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_Production.dbo.PR_SP_LINK_Stencil_Screen slss ON slss.StencilId = sps.Id
            INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_Production.dbo.PR_SP_Screen spsc  ON slss.ScreenId = spsc.Id
    END

    --item purchase orders
        SELECT DISTINCT ipo.* FROM LaunchPad3_Purchasing.dbo.PURCHASING_ItemPurchaseOrder ipo
            INNER JOIN #Jobs ej ON ej.OrderId = ipo.OrderId
        WHERE ipo.deleted = 0

    --purchase order items
    SELECT DISTINCT poi.*, ej.OrderId FROM LaunchPad3_Purchasing.dbo.PURCHASING_PurchaseOrderItem poi
        INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_Purchasing.dbo.PURCHASING_ItemPurchaseOrder ipo ON ipo.Id = poi.PurchaseOrderId
        INNER JOIN #Jobs ej ON ej.OrderId = ipo.OrderId
    WHERE ipo.deleted = 0

    --booking records
    SELECT DISTINCT bb.*, ej.OrderId, bb.Location AS location FROM LaunchPad3_Purchasing.dbo.BOOKING_Base bb
        INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_Purchasing.dbo.PURCHASING_ItemPurchaseOrder ipo ON ipo.Id = bb.PurchaseOrderId
        INNER JOIN #Jobs ej ON ej.OrderId = ipo.OrderId
    WHERE ipo.deleted = 0

    --booking items
    SELECT DISTINCT bi.*, ej.OrderId FROM LaunchPad3_Purchasing.dbo.BOOKING_Item bi
        INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_Purchasing.dbo.BOOKING_Base bb ON bi.BookingDataId = bb.Id
        INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_Purchasing.dbo.PURCHASING_ItemPurchaseOrder ipo ON ipo.Id = bb.PurchaseOrderId
        INNER JOIN #Jobs ej ON ej.orderid = ipo.orderid 
    WHERE ipo.deleted = 0

    -- items faults
    SELECT DISTINCT bif.* FROM LaunchPad3_Purchasing.dbo.BOOKING_ItemFault bif
        INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_Purchasing.dbo.PURCHASING_PurchaseOrderItem poi ON poi.Id = bif.PurchaseItemId
        INNER JOIN LaunchPad3_Purchasing.dbo.PURCHASING_ItemPurchaseOrder ipo ON ipo.Id = poi.PurchaseOrderId
        INNER JOIN #Jobs ej ON ej.orderid = ipo.OrderId
    WHERE ipo.deleted = 0

    --orderItemIds linked to purchase order items
    SELECT DISTINCT ppoiloi.PurchaseItemId AS Id, ppoiloi.OrderItemId
    FROM Launchpad3_Purchasing.dbo.PURCHASING_PurchaseOrderItem_LINK_OrderItem ppoiloi
        INNER JOIN Launchpad3_Purchasing.dbo.PURCHASING_PurchaseOrderItem poi ON ppoiloi.PurchaseItemId = poi.Id
        INNER JOIN Launchpad3_Purchasing.dbo.PURCHASING_ItemPurchaseOrder pipo ON pipo.Id = poi.PurchaseOrderId
        INNER JOIN #Jobs j ON j.OrderId = pipo.OrderId
    WHERE pipo.Deleted = 0

    -- stock locations
    SELECT 
    *
    , LocationType AS Type
    FROM LaunchPad3_Purchasing.dbo.STOCK_Location 

    -- get the highlight colours
    EXEC LaunchPad3_Core.dbo.HIGHLIGHTCOLOUR_GetAll

    --service suppliers
    EXEC LaunchPad3_OrderProcess.dbo.SERVICESUPPLIER_GetAll 29
    
    DROP TABLE #jobs
END
```

Comment: I don't have the full answer, but boy, there are a lot of DISTINCT queries in there. Are they truly necessary? Every one of those is aggregation, which can seriously slow things down, especially if it's not needed.

Comment: probably not but removing them doesn't seem to speed things up and I get some extra results in some of the queries.  Its more important that the result sets are correct and without duplication than gaining a few 10ths of a second.  The difference in time gained from merely moving the select statement further up was about a minute

Comment: Have you compared your SQL execution plans? Maybe the execution plan changes when you change the select order due to some caching of SQL server or something like that.

Comment: Two comments, first DISTINCT. If the data is the same using it or not, don't use it. Does it guarantee no duplicates? Yes. Does it come at a cost? Yes. If your data structures, joins, and WHERE clauses are correct, in most cases, you don't need DISTINCT. It sounds like you're using it as a safety net or something. Don't. It isn't free.

Comment: As to your problem, you do need to look at the execution plans as @SebastianS. is suggesting. However, I'd focus on the right plans, not all of them. So first, use Extended Events to capture all the individual statements execution metrics for this procedure. The events you're looking for rpc_completed and sp_statement_completed. I have a blog post that might help: https://www.scarydba.com/2020/10/12/most-costly-statement-in-a-stored-procedure/

Comment: the problem isn't the procedure itself guys.  You're focussing n the SQL.  When i ran it in SQL the whole thing loaded in about 3 seconds.  When I loaded it through our program in C#, for which I used dapper to create the various list objects, it loaded in over a minute, getting stuck on one  select statement.  When I moved the select statement further up the chain so it was executed earlier (and the corresponding dapper object compilation statement in the c# method) it loaded at the same speed as it did directly from SQL.  I'm trying to figure out why this would happen?

Comment: I will heed your advice on the using distinct though and checking the execution plans as well though, so thank you for that